# Solo Audio Track with DIfferent meter reading from Master?

Tags: audio, ableton, master

So I've created and processed my own kick drum sample with a generator, bounced it to 24-bit wave file. and went to place it in my song.  Now, this audio i have decided to process a little more with eq and sausage fattener

when i notice::

When i solo the With the audio of the kick and play just 1 sample, the audio channel says one dB value (e.g -3.5dB) and my Master channel will say -1.5dB... now how can that be?

I have no sends/returns on this channel enabled.

When i take off the additional eq and sausage fattener and leave just the pure audio file, the comparison is much closer between track dB and master dB, however, there is still a slight difference...My thoughts were that if only 1 track was playing the master channel would mirror the readings of that single track...

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Btw, I'm using Ableton Live 9 Suite if that makes any difference

Comment: So I've just now rendered the audio sample and the additional processing together into 1 audio sample, and after placing it into drum rack i still get the same results..... Single Solo channel reads -3.5dB and my master reads -1.5dB...

Answer (score 1):

Okay i'm a jerk :p

I just realized that i had left a 3 Band EQ on my master for when I was trying to see if i had enough presence in each 3 bands in my song.

even though each band was at unity gain i suppose there's a little bit of resonance between each band and that was causing the discrepancy

hehe woops :)

Comment: asked, commented & answered, all in one go - tick the box & award yourself some rep points ;-)

Comment: In seriousness though, thanks for letting us know what you found.  I'm sure you aren't the first to make this kind of mistake.